# my terminal and the Aperture Science logo

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I was wondering if it was at all possible to totally revamp my terminal. I want to put the Portal II Aperture Science logo in my terminal and have it stay there as if it is a mascot (or something). Here is the text link if anyone is curious:
http://jamisonjudd.com/2010/06/06/aperture-science-logo-in-text/

> I am running an x86 - 13.04
>   just in case that info might help, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why not set an actual picture of the logo as the terminal background?

Comment: the whole logo is either too big or too small :/ I guess you could say its a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit the .bashrc file of your terminal?
I saw [this](http://xmepux.deviantart.com/art/Aperture-Science-Terminal-262166195) and it looks pretty nice. you can edit it to show only the aperture logo.
Scroll down to the end of the file, where you can see the logo and edit it as you wish. Be carefull not to touch anything unless you know what it does.
To install, rename the file to ".bashrc" and put it in your home folder. **Be sure to make a backup of your current one!!**